# generic TValue is not enumerable

Tags: c#

```
 public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {                
            var parameterName = ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
            var values = expression.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);
            if (typeof (TValue) == typeof (List<SelectListItem>))
            {
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    but I get tvalue is not enumerable?? WHy?
                }
            }
```

What I am doing wrong? I wanto to get the list of all elements?

Comment: Ask yourself do you need a generic method when code inside isn't generic?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, there may be good reasons to do so. For example, see the implementation of `System.Xml.Linq.XElement.XElement(XName name, params object[] content)`. If some of the objects in `content` are enumerable, the constructor traverses them recursively to find all `XNode`s.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy That is not a good example. We're talking about generic methods here.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I got your point. Learned something new as well. I never knew it was possible to overload generics. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add [where constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx),

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
 where TValue : IEnumerable
{
}
```

Comment: Adding `where` might be too restrictive if `TValue` may be different from `List<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy, Where constraint can identify its derived classes like List<SelectListItem>, right?

Comment: Yes, but we don't have enough input to assume that the function is not intended to be called with `TValue`s other than those derived from `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy, in my opinion OP wants to create a method extension that is only targetted for collection property

Answer (score 3):

An object must have must implement either `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` for you to use it [in a foreach loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) (thanks for the comment @dcastro)

You're checking it in code but you're not guaranteeing it which means you're getting a compiler error.

I have to admit I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with the `expression.Compile()` but I would sugest you try casting it before going through the loop.

```
        var values = expression.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);
        if (typeof (TValue) == typeof (List<SelectListItem>))
        {
            var listValues = (List<SelectListItem>)values;
            foreach (var value in listValues )
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thx but I get error can not cast expression TValue to List<SelectListItem>

Comment: Cast it via `object` to make the compiler stop complaining. ie. `(List<...>)(object)values`

Comment: @senzacionale what exactly is values then?

Comment: A small addendum: the object doesn't have to implement `IEnumerable<T>` or even `IEnumerable`. It only has to have a public `IEnumerable GetEnumerable()` method.

Comment: @dcastro First off it is `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()`. Second not exactly. You don't need a implementation of `IEnumerator` at all, as long as the object has `MoveNext()`, `Current` property  foreach can enumerate it.

Comment: @dcastro However it's *super* rare to see an object provide such methods without also implementing `IEnumerable`; I've never seen it outside of an academic exercise.  It's only really relevant in that the feature also allows value types that implement `IEnumerable` to avoid being boxed, which it likely just isn't worth trying to avoid doing here.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel My bad, I meant `IEnumerator GetEnumerator`. I didn't know that the return type doesn't need to implement `IEnumerator` at all, thanks!